# How to get logging on terminalthe raw query in prisma, nestjs?

Tags: prisma

How to get logging on terminalthe raw query in prisma, nestjs?

I am setting up for logging using prisma and nestjs.

in my code:

```
 PrismaModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      prismaServiceOptions: {
        prismaOptions: { log: ['info', 'query']},
        explicitConnect: true,
      },
    }),
```

this is logging middleware

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

export function loggingMiddleware(): Prisma.Middleware {
  return async (params, next) => {
    const before = Date.now();

    const result = await next(params);

    const after = Date.now();

    console.log(
      `Query ${params.model}.${params.action} took ${after - before}ms`,
    );

    return result;
  };
}
```

this is my prismaService

```
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends PrismaClient<
    Prisma.PrismaClientOptions,
    'query | error | debug | info'
  >
  implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {

  private readonly logger = new Logger(PrismaService.name);
  constructor() {
    super({ log: [{ emit: 'event', level: 'query' }] });
    this.logger.log(`Prisma v${Prisma.prismaVersion.client}`);
    this.$on('query', (e) => this.logger.debug(`${e.query} ${e.params}`));
  }
  // constructor() {
  //   super({
  //     log: [
  //       { emit: 'event', level: 'query' },
  //       { emit: 'stdout', level: 'info' },
  //       { emit: 'stdout', level: 'warn' },
  //       { emit: 'stdout', level: 'error' },
  //     ],
  //     errorFormat: 'colorless',
  //   });
  // }

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.$disconnect();
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on('beforeExit', async (event) => {
      console.log(event.name);
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}
```

I want to show raw query on terminal like TypeORM. But I can get anything on terminal.
How do I configure prisma logging correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to print all log levels to stdout is to pass in an array LogLevel objects:

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: ['query', 'info', 'warn', 'error'],
})
```

This is the short form of passing in an array of LogDefinition objects where the value of emit is always stdout:

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: [
    {
      emit: 'stdout',
      level: 'query',
    },
    {
      emit: 'stdout',
      level: 'error',
    },
    {
      emit: 'stdout',
      level: 'info',
    },
    {
      emit: 'stdout',
      level: 'warn',
    },
  ],
})
```

For more information on logging using Prisma, Please check the [docs on logging](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/logging#log-to-stdout).

Answer (score 0):

When importing the Prisma Module into to `app.module.ts`. You can config option log in the field `prismaOptions`

```
PrismaModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      prismaServiceOptions: {
        middlewares: [
          // configure your prisma middleware
          loggingMiddleware({
            logger: new Logger('PrismaMiddleware'),
            logLevel: 'log',
          }),
        ],
        prismaOptions: {
          log: ['query', 'info', 'warn', 'error'],
        },
      },
    }),
```

[image]